# I have a problem with a html page

Tags: javascript, html

i seem to be having a problem getting this to work right, i am making a download page for a site, and it wont seem to download. any help is appreciated, the download site i need help with is http://itouchvip.com/firmwares/indextest.html

Comment: You also seem to have forgotten to ask a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
<!-- Browser Version Too Old
```

from your script ..

It is marking all your script as a comment and so your `golink` function is not defined when you click the button .

Comment: omg thank you. someone told me to put that there :(